# Visual Studio c# Internet connectivity

Tags: c#

I am working on a Visual Studio 2010 C# web form application. I have this working apart from a display message when the application looses its internet connection. As it stands, when an internet connection can ot be found it displays a blank screen. In my coding I have some code which should catch a comms disconnection and display "Trying to connect ...[{0}]" with a countdown in seconds. The issue I have is the message is not displaying. Can any one see where I am going wrong.

My MainForm.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Dis_Browser
{
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        if (!InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation.IsBrowserEmulationSet())
        {
            InternetExplorerBrowserEmulation.SetBrowserEmulationVersion();
        }
        InitializeComponent();
        Cursor.Hide();
    }



    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        browser.DocumentTitleChanged += ValidateConnection;
        //this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private bool offline;
    private void ValidateConnection(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (offline)
            return;

        //if (browser.DocumentTitle == "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" || browser.DocumentTitle == "Navigation Canceled" || browser.DocumentTitle == "This page can&rsquo;t be displayed" || browser.DocumentTitle == "Broadband Link - Error")
        if (browser.DocumentTitle != string.Empty)
        {
            offline = true;
            browser.Visible = false;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj => WaitConnection());
            return;
        }

        browser.Visible = true;
    }

    private int countdown = 20;
    private void WaitConnection()
    {
        while (!Native.IsOnline("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => { connectLbl.Text = String.Format(" Trying to connect ...[{0}]", countdown--); }));
            if (countdown == 0)
                countdown = 20;
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }

        offline = false;
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>
            {
                browser.Refresh();
                browser.Visible = true;
                countdown = 20;
            }));
    }

    private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void connectLbl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class Native
{
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool InternetCheckConnection(string lpszUrl, int dwFlags, int dwReserved);
    public static bool IsOnline(string url)
    {
        return InternetCheckConnection(url, 1, 0);
    }


}
}
```

My MainForm.Designer.cs

namespace Dis_Browser
    {
    partial class MainForm
    {
        /// 
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// 
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        this.connectLbl = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // browser
        // 
        this.browser.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.browser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.browser.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.browser.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        this.browser.Name = "browser";
        this.browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        this.browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        this.browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        this.browser.TabIndex = 0;
        this.browser.Url = new System.Uri("http://www.google.com", System.UriKind.Absolute);
        this.browser.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.browser_DocumentCompleted);
        // 
        // connectLbl
        // 
        this.connectLbl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.connectLbl.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 48F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
        this.connectLbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.connectLbl.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        this.connectLbl.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        this.connectLbl.Name = "connectLbl";
        this.connectLbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        this.connectLbl.TabIndex = 1;
        this.connectLbl.Text = " Trying to connect ...[20] Please check your Internet router";
        this.connectLbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        this.connectLbl.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.connectLbl_Click);
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        this.Controls.Add(this.browser);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Dis Systems";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainForm_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label connectLbl;
}
}
```

I know there are many ways to write this but this is my attempt. Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Is it possible to switch to the latest version of visual studio

Comment: It's possible but it would mean building a new windows machine which would run the latest version. Would the latest version make or easier to resolve my issue.

Comment: @k7s5a I have installed Visual Studio Community 2017 on a new PC. Can you help me resolve my issue or should I attempt to rebuild the application in the newer version of VS? Thanks.

Comment: @k7s5a Hi, I did as you recommended and I am now running Visual Studio 2017. Can you or anyone else try and help me resolve my issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Try and debug this: is WaitConnection called? Is connectLbl.Text set to anything (which for some reason isn't displayed)?

Comment: @Hans Kesting Hi again. When debugging I am getting the following "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'" which gets flagged in the MainForm.Designer.cs.


this.browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080); // System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred     HResult=0x80004005     Message=Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.